# Need to Invoke lambda function using jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, aws-lambda, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to invoke AWS Lambda function using Jenkinsfile with the payload. Not able to inject the instance_ip variable into the payload.

```
def instance_ip = "10.X.X.X"
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
   stage('Terminate Machine') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh(script: 'aws lambda invoke  --function-name terminate-instance --payload  '{"private_ip_address":"${instance_ip}" }')          
        }            
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to scape some characters and set --incvocation-type as Event:

```
          sh(script: "aws lambda invoke \
                    --function-name 'terminate-instance' \
                    --invocation-type Event \
                    --payload '{ \"private_ip_address\":\"${instance_ip}\" }' \
                    /tmp/response.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. So to pass the payload, in Jenkins file, I am creating a Json payload file using echo and then passing it to the aws cli. It may not be the cleanest solution but it works. Here's what my code looks like:

```
echo '{ "tagKey"':'"'"${tagKey}"'"', '"tagValue"':'"'"${tagValue}"'"', '"region"':'"'"${region}"'"' } > json.json
    
 cat json.json
 ls -alrt
   
 aws lambda invoke --function-name tag_remediator --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload file://json.json out_"$tagKey".txt --region "${region}"
```